# Forgot a password link error

Tags: administration

I am an admin. People in my organization often say that they do not get a email when they use forgot my password link. and this happens with people who use this option before 8 AM, on other time like in the middle of the day , forgot password works fine.

What could be the issue with the time here? Does using forgot password link at particular time really matters?

Comment: What is you org Business Hours settings? Check for the the settings. Setup -> Company Profile -> Business Hours

Comment: Its 8 AM to 6 PM

Comment: How does this matter? How is it connected to "forgot my password link"?

Comment: You are correct it should not matter. Unless there is no profile based login hour setting. Next one reason should be the Email Deliverability. It should Not be No Access and look for System Audit history you may get some answer.

Comment: Let us know what was the solution after fixing the issue. Here is one post hope it may help you. https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h1ZpAAI